# Getting element (button) data attribute with vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, liquid

I have the following html div.  The {{ }} represent liquid syntax and it renders server side.

```
  <div class="two columns">
    <button 
      data-value='{{ value }}'
      class="button-selection"
      :class="selectionButtonClass($event)"
      @click="selectionButton($event)" 
    >
      <span class="text">{{ value }}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

In a vue 3 instance I have the following method in the same page.

```
    selectionButtonClass(el) {
      console.log('checking val');
      console.log(el);
    }
```

My goal is to set a conditional class in the selectionButton method but I can't get the element to get the data attribute.  The above appears in the console log as undefined.  However the @click does show the event obviously it's recognize the onclick but not the class method check.

Comment: You don't really need to access the `data-value` attribute because liquid already has its value (i.e, `{{ value }}`). Can't liquid just render the button with the class based on `value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$event` is only available to event handlers. `@click="selectionButton($event)"` defines an inline event handler, while `:class="selectionButtonClass($event)"` is not an event handler.

To get the element, you need to add a `ref` attribute to the `<button>`:

```html
    <button 
      ref="selectionButton"
      data-value='{{ value }}'
      class="button-selection"
      :class="selectionButtonClass($event)"
      @click="selectionButton($event)" 
    >
```

And access it by `this.$refs.selectionButton`, assuming you are using the options API. However, the ref is available only after the component is mounted. Thus you need to handle the case where the ref is `null`.

More on template refs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html

Since you are using server side rendering, I think it would be better to render the value as a parameter of the `selectionButton` function on the server side.